# Como eliminar ou ocultar a digitação de senha de acesso aos dados de um servidor com SQL Server a partir do VBA ou macro do Excel?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel, vba

Estou realizando um serviço de migração de um banco de dados de um servidor com **SQL Server** em uma empresa, mas solicitaram que eu intermediasse a migração em Planilhas do **Excel**, pois eles querem assim nesta primeira fase para adiantar alguns tratamentos em planilha mesmo.

Eu não tenho experiência alguma com **SQL Server**, mas sim com **Excel** **avançado** e **VBA**, e com o auxílio de um técnico que manipula o **SQL Server** de forma básica eu criei uma macro e depois adaptei para como está apresentada abaixo; e ela funcionou neste primeiro teste que fiz.

```
   For i = 1 To 3

   Select Case i

      Case 1
         Sheets("Plan1").Select
         N = "BD1"

      Case 2
         Sheets("Plan3").Select
         N = "BD2"

      Case 3
         Sheets("Plan5").Select
         N = "BD3"

   End Select

   With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Data Source=10.0.0.5\sqlexpress;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Trans", _
        "late=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=LABORATORIO;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=Fals", "e;Initial Catalog=Dados"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("""Dados"".""dbo""." & N & "")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceConnectionFile = _
        "C:\10.0.0.5_sqlexpress Dados " & N & ".odc"
        .ListObject.DisplayName = _
        "Tabela__10.0.0.5_sqlexpress_Dados_" & N
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Cells.Select

    Selection.Copy

    Select Case i

       Case 1
          Sheets("Plan2").Select

       Case 2
          Sheets("Plan4").Select

       Case 3
          Sheets("Plan6").Select
    End Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

   Range("A1").Select

Next i
```

Em **Plan1** os primeiros dados são abertos perfeitamente, e é feita uma cópia deles para **Plan2** colando tudo como "valores"; para os outros dois ocorre o mesmo, só que é **Plan3** com **Plan 4** e depois **Plan5** com **Plan6**.

Trata-se de um teste inicial, por isso ficou desta forma, irei melhorar assim que funcionar o que preciso.

As abas pares ficam com os dados como o cliente quer. O meu problema é que esses dados são de um sistema que será desativado é são mais de 400 tabelas (não digitei errado não) para migrar.

Da forma que está, em cada "loop" é solicitada a senha de acesso ao banco de dados.

Não encontrei como colocar via macro ou **VBA** essa senha para que tudo seja feito automaticamente, sem interrupção (digitação da senha em um *popup*).

Alguém pode me ajudar? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo veja se a função abaixo te atende:

```
Sub SQLConnect(servername As String, dbname As String, tablename As String, uname As String, pword As String, sheetname as String)

'******************************************************
' Login no Servidor
'******************************************************
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

' Teste 1 - Usando conexão direta:    
On Error GoTo ErrHand
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & servername & _
            ";Database=" & dbname & ";" & _
            "Uid=" & uname & ";" & _
            "Pwd=" & pword
            .Open
    End With

' Teste 2 - Usando conexão OLEDB:
' On Error GoTo ErrHand
'   With cn
'        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & servername & ";" & _
'            "Initial Catalog=" & dbname & ";" & _
'            "User ID=" & uname & ";" & _
'            "Password=" & pword & ";"
'            .Open
'    End With

    Call MsgBox("Conexão com o banco de dados OK!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sucesso")

'******************************************************
' Faz a consulta SQL
'******************************************************
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlString As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sqlString = "SELECT * from " & tablename
rs.Open sqlString, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
cn.Execute (sqlString)

'******************************************************
' Coloca dados na planilha
'******************************************************
Dim fld as ADODB.Field
Dim iSheet as Integer

iSheet = Sheets(sheetname).Index

' Cria o cabeçalho
i = 0 
With Worksheets(iSheet).Range("A1") 
  For Each fld In rs.Fields 
   .Offset(0, i).Value = fld.Name 
   i = i + 1 
 Next fld 
End With 

' Transfere os dados
Worksheets(iSheet).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

ExitHere:
 On Error Resume Next
 cn.Close
 Set cn = Nothing
 Err.Clear
 Exit Sub

ErrHand:
 MsgBox "Conexão não definida.", vbExclamation
 Resume ExitHere

End Sub
```

Adaptei essa função desta [fonte](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/280390-visual-basic-applications-log-into-sql-server-login.html), infelizmente **não pude testar**.

Comment: Evert, grato pelo retorno, no momento não tenho como testar também, e desconheço o SQL Server, não sei se faz sentido o que pensei. Se eu adicionar ao Whit que tenho o .ConnectionString = "Pwd=minha_senha"  resolveria? Já que a macro está funcionando, abrindo os dados e trazendo para o Excel?

Comment: Acho que teria de adaptar melhor então para usar sua função atual, pois, pela função que colocou não deve estar usando o _object_ `ADODB.Connection`, está? Se sim, vai sim! Se não, terá de adaptar seu `with` para usar a conexão como está ai... mas teste esta função pois acho que vai rodar bem ai. Acho!

Comment: Ótimo, vou fazer isso, e testar sua função, grato

Comment: Vi que está usando **OLEDB** vou alterar o código para ficar com **OLEDB** também para poder testar.

Comment: O que está ai foi gerado automaticamente via macro, ativei a macro e o operador do servidor fez o acesso, dai gravou assim.

Comment: ahh entendi! legal! mas acho que vai funcionar de um jeito ou de outro.

Comment: Tentarei testar ainda hoje. Valeu

Comment: Evert, na sua rotina esta dando o erro "O tipo definido pelo usuário não foi definido", em "Dim cn As ADODB.Connection"

Comment: Só adicionar a referencia, veja aqui: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w 

No projeto vba vá em projetos referencia e adicione: Microsoft ADO Ext. for DDL and Security and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library